# I am getting execute function error

Tags: php, mysqli

```
<?php 
include 'dbconnect.php';
 ob_start();
 session_start();


 $username = "";
 $password = "";

 if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    }


 $sql= 'SELECT * FROM login WHERE username=:username AND password=:password';

 $query = $link->prepare($sql);

 $query->execute(array(':username' => $username, ':password' => $password));


 if(mysqli_num_rows($query)== 0){
  header('Location: index.php?err=1');
 }else{

  $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);

  session_regenerate_id();
  $_SESSION['sess_user_id'] = $row['id'];
  $_SESSION['sess_username'] = $row['username'];
  $_SESSION['sess_userrole'] = $row['role'];

  echo $_SESSION['sess_userrole'];
  session_write_close();

  if( $_SESSION['sess_userrole'] == "admin"){
   header('Location: admin.php');
  }else{
   header('Location: user.php');
  }

  }

?>
```

I am getting this error may i know where am i going wrong just to learn better "Call to a member function execute() on boolean" Help me with a better solution
The database is connected and also form input username and password is correct also the below statement is correct need help with this query execute part

Comment: Looks like `$link` has not been declared / initialised

Comment: looks like `$link->prepare($sql)` is failing and returning `false`.

Comment: <?php
$link =mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "","task");
if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
?>

Comment: i have included dbconnect.php <?php
$link =mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "","task");
if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
?>

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = $link->prepare($sql);
```

is returning false instead of an object, when you try to run an object function on "false" it fails.

```
$query = $link->prepare($sql);
if ($query instanceof {whatever object type it has to be})
{
     $query->execute(array(':username' => $username, ':password' => $password));
     // rest of your code
}else{
     throw new \Exception("query builder failed");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php):

> If the database server successfully prepares the statement,
>   PDO::prepare() returns a PDOStatement object. If the database server
>   cannot successfully prepare the statement, PDO::prepare() returns
>   FALSE or emits PDOException (depending on error handling).

Since `execute` is tried to be called on a `boolean`, it means that `prepare` returned `FALSE`, so the statement was not successfully prepared. You need to check your query's correctness. Is your table and fields existent? If you run such a query with arbitrary values for `username` and `password`, will it be successfully executed? Wild guess: you might have a problem with `password`, which is a keyword as well, you might want to use password instead of `password` in your query.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this in dbconnect.php

```
    $link = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=task', 'root', '');
```